# Facebook Thumbnails Issue Traced to safe_image.php

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

For some reason, facebook's safe_image.php script isn't generating thumbnails, properly. It's generating a 1x1 image... even though the correct image is linked in the script's parameters.
Example:

```
<img class="img" alt="" src="https://s-external.ak.fbcdn.net
/safe_image.php?d=AQBtrCt_Es_KsED0&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F
%2Fwww.southlapatriots.info%2Fimages%2FScamra%2FJayCastilleCouncil2.jpg"
```

The linked image is correct, but it is still only generating a 1x1 image.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem today, in my case was an https issue.

I automatically redirect every http requests to https, and while the browser works this out normally, FB's safe_image.php doesn't. If you have such redirect as well, you may want to disable it for just your og:image file.

Answer (score 2):

I also get into a similar problem. My problem is because of the image name has a "space" in it. so it is not appear in the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and also in sharing.

So i fixed the issue by replace space with hyphen("-") through coding part. After that i debug the url in [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it appears. That means Facebook wont show the image name with "space". But there is no logical reason behind this. Anyway it will help someone.

For more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216164/3049065) posted by [Patrick D'appollonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012139/patrick-dappollonio). It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sort of gzip compression for your images? We are seeing a similar issue, but we compress our image with gzip and set the headers. Browsers are rendering fine, but Facebook is essentially displaying nothing.

Comment: Jay, I just checked for compression, and i'm pretty sure it's not compressed. Deflate and Header are not enabled and Joomla is not running any type of compression.

Answer (score 0):

safe_image script code doesn't support having a % in the app's image url (which is probably why the image turns into a 1x1 transparent pixel)

so the solution is [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13632) . Try to follow the instruction in the first comment by chris

Comment: If you're referring to the comment about the time stamp, the original image doesn't have one. The original meta looks like this:

    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.southlapatriots.info/images/Scamra/JayCastilleCouncil2.jpg"/>

It's the safe_image.php script code that's inserting the "?"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the directory including genuine targeted images is under "`.htaccess`" control, in which images being called from external server is prohibited.

Example of blocking "`.htaccess`" file such as:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www.mysite.jp" ref_ok
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=ref_ok
</FilesMatch>
```