# Sometimes get solid turquoise image using Facebook Audience Network SDK on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, url, facebook-audience-network

I am using the latest [Facebook Audience Network Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api) to request a native ad in my app.  Quite often, when we render the ad it displays a solid blank, turquoise/green image.

An example URL returned from the SDK (link will probably die soon):

`https://www.facebook.com/adnw_creative?u1=https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCNTQau5nEI97JV&w=400&h=400&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQKuuUwxdpWnJD4IuVU5K7-dGtdpWvTMkkcn8An7JTLMP1uGH8-5hr3r0Qxlw7uKt-Daa8U2FJ11odkIHEh7Ov506EldRlGwnGO8D2z7Y5SbNg7uLC5PiMOID0g6Jxa9ZqPqmgdGRZFhfRXcAK4XXu-h&cfs=1&ext=jpg&w1=400&h1=400&u2=https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBVQQYgyM2PGHkl&w=400&h=400&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQIV9UKQ9Tr1kQ3DDHhoRHMJFyAdfC0P_yEeDxw283SgyGNnVCcU0KylESx5DdC46BC8SYmXafctY15OOW41B_rnKKL2CZKGjqVe5QdKJddBb2iWJwdd1rdoLUaRo0DeMkC785yfI89iPJHtm9ng9nxo&cfs=1&ext=jpg&w2=400&h2=400`

Image (630 x 315px, ignore the "sponsored" text rendered by us):

[image]

I've tried the link on my laptop, and it gives the same result.  The URL has two levels of redirection:

```
https://www.facebook.com/adnw_creative
    ?u1=https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php
        ?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads...
    &u2=https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php
        ?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads...
```

The two `safe_image.php` links within this URL both work, e.g.

URL:

`https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCNTQau5nEI97JV&w=400&h=400&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQKuuUwxdpWnJD4IuVU5K7-dGtdpWvTMkkcn8An7JTLMP1uGH8-5hr3r0Qxlw7uKt-Daa8U2FJ11odkIHEh7Ov506EldRlGwnGO8D2z7Y5SbNg7uLC5PiMOID0g6Jxa9ZqPqmgdGRZFhfRXcAK4XXu-h&cfs=1&ext=jpg&w1=400&h1=400`

Image (315 x 315px):

[image]

This proves that something is going wrong with the top level `adnw_creative` URL.  It looks like it should be stitching together the two 315 x 315px images into a single 630 x 315px image, but is failing.

Searching around for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084172/facebook-thumbnails-issue-traced-to-safe-image-php) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325790/sharing-a-link-doesnt-post-image), people have had URL encoding and scheme (http/https) issues with safe_image.php, but this is a different issue.

Any thoughts on reliably getting a decent image?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are able to reliably reproduce this, then I would create a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) report.

Comment: @ifaour Thanks, I did this and they pointed me in the direction of Charles for debugging.

Comment: glad that helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the Facebook URL encoding was being broken by a third party Cordova plugin, which was not URL-encoding it before passing from Android to JavaScript via webView.loadUrl().

Fix suggested [here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads/issues/30).

I debugged the issue by using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/) to see what the Facebook SDK was actually retrieving.